# How do I detect mouse movement?

Tags: command-line, scripts, xorg, mouse

I am trying to come up with a script that will run a command if mouse movement is detected. When it is run, it just hangs.

```
#!/bin/bash
# 

xidle -delay 5 -sw -program "/home/andy/bin/test.sh" -timeout 300
exit 0

#!/bin/bash
# Ubuntu_Mate 18.04 LTS

gxmessage -fg red -font  'sans 30' -timeout 3  'Mouse movement has been detected. '
#exit 0
```

If I run `sudo -i` and run this, it will react to a mouse movement.

```
read -r -n1 TMP </dev/input/mice
```

Is `sudo -i` the only option?

Comment: Seen this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49546/bash-script-to-detect-and-record-mouse-movements/49548

Comment: xinput test 9 shows the mouse coordinates when mouse is moved. I need it to do a command upon mouse movement.

Comment: @fixit7 could you tell a bit more what needs to be done on mousemove? solution depends on that. scripted (interpreted) solutions, using system calls, are significantly more consuming than compiled ones, even at a lower time resolution.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to detect any mouse movement and then run a command if so. A compiled solution would be fine. @Jacob Vlijm

Comment: I understand, but what is the nature of the command? I am asking because even if you only launch on state change (moving/not movng) triggers will be potentially quite many.

Comment: gxmessage -fg red -font  'sans 30' -timeout 3  'Mouse movement has been detected. ' @Jacob Vlijm